# Limit download count with text file in PHP

Tags: php, time, download, count, limit

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && $_GET['download']==='1')
{
    $handle = fopen('lastdownload.txt','rw');
    $date = @fread($handle,filesize('lastdownload.txt'));

    if (time() - 30 * 60 > $date)
    {
    fwrite($handle,time());
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="dwnld_'.date('d_m_Y_H_i',filemtime('download.zip')).'.zip"');
    readfile('download.zip');
    }

    exit;
}
```

Hi everyone, i have a problem about limiting download count.

I want to limit my download count.

If someone request the file with ?download=1

It checks the current time and the time inside the file

If 30 minutes passed before the last download, it lets you download again, else it just exits.

Any help please?

Thank you.

Comment: Question is unclear.  Your code seems reasonably correct.  It should allow the file to be downloaded only every 30 minutes.  Since you're just storing the download time in a text file, this 30 minute increment will apply to all users.  So if Joe downloads the file a 01:00, and Suzy tries at 01:20, Suzy won't get the file.

Maybe you should edit your question and be more specific about what's not working, or what you're not sure how to do.

Comment: Only 1 person will use this file, so Only Joe will download it, no other poeple like Suzy.

Code is not working. It's not writing to the file. That's why i can download anytime. lastdownload.txt is always empty.

Comment: It is possible for the file I/O functions in PHP to be disabled for security reasons (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.disable-functions)

Comment: Yeah, I'd store the timestamp in a database. Writing to the same folder as the script can bring all sorts of permissions problems.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your still using PHP4, I would just use [`file_put_contents()`](http://uk.php.net/file_put_contents) and [`file_get_contents()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Answer (score 0):

"rw" is not a valid mode for fopen. You should use "r+" or "x+" and rewind the file pointer after reading:

```
$handle = fopen('lastdownload.txt','r+');
$date = @fread($handle,filesize('lastdownload.txt'));
rewind($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(fileatime("lastdownload.txt")>=300)
    {
    //Access OR File Download Code Here
    }
```